# How Do I Build Just a Plugin Without Rebuilding the Entire Project?

Tags: c++, plugins, cmake

I have a C++ project I wrote which uses CMake as a build system, and am having issues trying to compile only a specific plugin in the project, opposed to rebuilding the entire code base. In the project's CMake GUI, I set the following:

```
src folder: /home/gaurab/Desktop/project/src

build folder: /home/gaurab/Desktop/project/build/v17.06
```

Then I built a minimal plugin to test it, which I then placed in:

```
/home/gaurab/Desktop/project/src/applications/plugins/MyPlugin
```

This directory contains the following files:

```
initMyPlugin.h, initMyPlugin.cpp, CMakeLists.txt
```

I was told to put the src folder as same as above i.e.

```
src folder: /home/gaurab/Desktop/project/src
```

Won't this rebuild the whole project again? I was hoping that I could just rebuild the plugin component of the project. I tried the following the in CMake GUI:

```
src folder: /home/gaurab/Desktop/project/src/applications/plugins/MyPlugin
build folder: /home/gaurab/Desktop/project/src/applications/plugins/MyPlugin/build
```

Which resulted in errors.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Plugin is an entire pattern of adding modules to a program without rewriting/modifying the program.  How exactly your plugin architecture works is utterly unclear.

Comment: Whether recompilation happen depends mostly on your CMake code.